# Draw grid on writable area with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw below image on A4 paper with tikz.The grids should be cover all writable area.

[image]

I have searched it on many site but still not figure out how to do it with tikz.

Comment: Look at the grid operation `\path . . . grid[ options ] corner . . . ;`, possibly in conjunction with `overlay`

Comment: 'All writeable area' means what? I've interpreted this to mean the entire paper, but your image suggests maybe not. If you mean the whole *printable* area, that depends entirely on your printer and printer driver. So I've taken 'writeable' to be places a human could handwrite i.e. all over the paper.

Comment: @cfr Writable area means the valid area which will write text on. The width is the linewidth, the height should be the total lines each page.I am not sure if it's the area except the margins.

Comment: @lucky1928 Well, the writeable area is the whole page if you use zero margins. `\linewidth` can be `\paperwidth` in that case. The total lines per page will vary not only between documents but within documents. You can use `\textheight` but some pages will have text which ends before the end of the the text block. (Unless you are doing something special such as configuring for grid typesetting, but that's complicated and cannot be completely implemented at the current time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can use `pgfplots` for this.

## Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style = {dashed, Green}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style = {solid, Green}}
    \begin{figure}\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[Green]
        \begin{axis}[grid = both,
                     ticks = none,
                     minor tick num = 1,
                     xmin = 0,
                     ymin = 0,
                     xmax = 17,
                     ymax = 26,
                     width = 17cm,
                     height = 26cm,
                     scale only axis]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Update

If you want a 2cm separation on grid, one thing you can do is to use `ytick`and `xtick` options, as follows:

```
     \begin{axis}[grid = both,
                 ticks = none,
                 minor tick num = 1,
                 xmin = 0,
                 ymin = 0,
                 xmax = 16,
                 ymax = 26,
                 xtick = {0, 2,..., 16},
                 ytick = {0, 2,..., 26},
                 width = 16cm,
                 height = 26cm,
                 scale only axis]
    \end{axis}
```

Comment: Cool, how to adjust the grid width? Is it 1cm by default?

Comment: One solution is to use `ytick` and `xtick` options to define where major ticks will be into the grid (solid lines).

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure this is a duplicate but this is quicker: http://michaelgoerz.net/notes/printable-paper-with-latex-and-tikz.html and take your pick.

Modifying Michael Goerz's grid a little, for example:

```
% Minor adaptions from http://michaelgoerz.net/notes/printable-paper-with-latex-and-tikz.html
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} % for A4 size paper
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\colorlet{dlines}{green!25!black}
\colorlet{llines}{green!25!gray}
\tikzset{
  dashed lines/.style={llines, very thin, densely dashed},
  strong lines/.style={dlines, very thin},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[style=dashed lines,step=10mm] (current page.south west) grid +(210mm,297mm);
  \draw[style=strong lines,step=20mm] (current page.south west) grid +(210mm,297mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: greenish grid]

Given the [weirdness of `grid`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271066/how-to-align-overlaid-grid-in-tikz), modifying it a bit more:

```
% Major adaptions from http://michaelgoerz.net/notes/printable-paper-with-latex-and-tikz.html
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} % for A4 size paper
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\colorlet{dlines}{green!25!black}
\colorlet{llines}{green!25!gray}
\tikzset{
  dashed lines/.style={llines, very thin, densely dashed},
  strong lines/.style={dlines, very thin},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \foreach \i in {5,25,...,205} \draw [strong lines] (current page.south west) ++(\i mm,8.5mm) -- ++(0,280mm);
  \foreach \i in {15,35,...,195} \draw [dashed lines] (current page.south west) ++(\i mm,8.5mm) -- ++(0,280mm);
  \foreach \i in {8.5,28.5,...,288.5} \draw [strong lines] (current page.south west) ++(5mm,\i mm) -- ++(200mm,0);
  \foreach \i in {18.5,38.5,...,278.5} \draw [dashed lines] (current page.south west) ++(5mm,\i mm) -- ++(200mm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: other greenish grid]

Comment: No, I think it's different topic.

Comment: @lucky1928 How can you think it is a different topic from a question which I think is a duplicate but haven't found?

Answer (score 3):

It's a math game in tikz. One more example as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \def\width{1.5cm}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\offset}{\width+0.4cm}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\rows}{floor(\textheight/\offset)-1}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\cols}{floor(\textwidth/\width)-1}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\dx}{(\textwidth-(1+\cols)*\width)/2}
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\dy}{(\textheight-(1+\rows)*\offset)/2}

    \coordinate (O) at ([xshift=\dx,yshift=-\dy]current page text area.north west);

    \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\cols}{
      \foreach \j in {0,1,...,\rows} {
        \draw[blue,thick] ([xshift=\i*\width,yshift=-\j*\offset]O) rectangle ++(\width,-\width);;
        \draw[blue!40,dashed] ([xshift=\i*\width,yshift=-\width/2-\j*\offset]O) -- ++ (\width,0)
            ([xshift=\width/2+\i*\width,yshift=-\j*\offset]O) -- ++ (0,-\width);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tikz` and `tikzpagenodes` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \draw[blue,step=1cm] (current page text area.south west) grid (current page text area.north east);
     \draw[blue!50,dashed,,step=5mm] (current page text area.south west) grid (current page text area.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want this on every page, use `background` package.

Besides `grid` option, one can also draw these manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     %% Vertical lines
     \foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,1.1}{
     \draw[blue] ([xshift=\x*\textwidth]current page text area.south west) --
                 ([xshift=\x*\textwidth]current page text area.north west);
}
    \foreach \x in {0.05,0.1,...,1}{
      \draw[blue!40,dashed] ([xshift=\x*\textwidth]current page text area.south west) --
                 ([xshift=\x*\textwidth]current page text area.north west);
}

   %% horizontal lines
    \foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,1.1}{
     \draw[blue] ([yshift=\x*\textheight]current page text area.south west) --
                 ([yshift=\x*\textheight]current page text area.south east);
}
    \foreach \x in {0.05,0.1,...,1}{
      \draw[blue!40,dashed] ([yshift=\x*\textheight]current page text area.south west) --
                 ([yshift=\x*\textheight]current page text area.south east);
}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This grid will exactly occupy the writable area. Try to change the margin and see yourself. Further, the density of grid can be varied by changing the sequence in the `\foreach` loop.

Comment: Cool, it will be good answer if we can remove the partial grid on the border.

Comment: @lucky1928 For that you have to adjust the `step` suitably. Make it an exact fraction of width and height. There is also `xtep` and `ystep` so that they can be separately controlled.

Comment: @lucky1928 I have edited the answer with another option.