# How to align overlaid grid in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In trying to adjust [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270995/draw-grid-on-writable-area-with-tikz/270999#270999) in light of the OP's comments on another one, I discovered that I could not straightforwardly align an overlaid grid so that the steps began from the same point as the grid.

Why doesn't this work and how is this supposed to be done?

The code (minus my added bugs) is adapted from one of [Michael Goerz's examples](http://michaelgoerz.net/notes/printable-paper-with-latex-and-tikz.html).

```
% Minor adaptions from http://michaelgoerz.net/notes/printable-paper-with-latex-and-tikz.html
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} % for A4 size paper
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\colorlet{dlines}{green!25!black}
\colorlet{llines}{green!25!gray}
\tikzset{
  dashed lines/.style={llines, very thin, densely dashed},
  strong lines/.style={dlines, very thin},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[style=dashed lines] (current page.south west) ++(5mm,8.5mm) coordinate (a) grid [step=10mm] ++(200mm,280mm) coordinate (b);
  \draw[style=strong lines] (a) rectangle (b);
  \draw[style=strong lines] (a) grid [step=20mm] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: misaligned grid]

Comment: You get a similar issue if you attempt to use this construction in beamer to make a rectangle that covers the page. It does not go exactly to the edge. No idea why.

Comment: @daleif I think that's a different issue. I'm not trying to start right at the edge in this case - starting right at the edge would work. It is starting a bit in and a bit up which seems problematic.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am running it twice. That's not the problem.

Answer (score 6):

In place to use `\draw (a) grid (b);` you can use `\draw[shift={(a)}] (0,0) grid (b);` to have a grid starting from the bottom left corner.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} % for A4 size paper
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\colorlet{dlines}{green!25!black}
\colorlet{llines}{green!25!gray}
\tikzset{
  dashed lines/.style={llines, very thin, densely dashed},
  strong lines/.style={dlines, very thin},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[style=dashed lines, shift={(current page.south west)},shift={(5mm,8.5mm)}] (0,0) coordinate (a) grid [step=10mm] (200mm,280mm) coordinate (b);
  \draw[style=strong lines] (a) rectangle (b);
  \draw[style=strong lines, shift={(a)}] (0,0) grid [step=20mm] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a neat workaround - thanks! I didn't think to try a double-shift like that. But do you know why it is needed? Why is my code wrong exactly?

Comment: @cfr because this is how `grid` works : it starts always from (0,0). Try to draw `\draw (.5,.5) grid +(5,5);`. The bad news is that I don't know some parameter `start grid from=...`. The good news is that we can make start `grid` from another point if we add a shift.

Comment: That's not what the manual says, though. It says `It is important to note that the grid is always “phased” such that it contains the point (0, 0) if that point
happens to be inside the rectangle.` But here that's not the case, is it?

Comment: Or is `(0,0)` at `(current page.center)`?

Comment: @cfr no, the zero point is not at `(current page.center)`, it is at the position where your image is on the page. And I think that the documentation is ok if you remove "if that point happens to be inside the rectangle", because in any case, if no transformations are present, the grid is aligned at (0,0).

Comment: Er... so the documentation is, in fact, *not* OK. That is, if you have to rewrite it to make it OK, then it really can't be OK to start with.

Comment: @cfr the documentations is "almost" ok, as I said it is "ok if you remove ..." ;) but in your particular case it is ok, because the point (0,0) is inside your rectangle. Draw a circle at (0,0) and you will see.

Comment: That sentence in the documentation means that zero on both increment list is contained. For example `\draw[style=help lines] (1.5,1.5) grid[step=1] (3,3);` will be an open box at the lower left but `\draw[style=help lines] (1,1) grid[step=1] (3,3);` will be closed. That's what is meant by the *phased*. Even though not drawn, it is assumed *as if* origin was visible.

Comment: @percusse we all agree on how it works and what "phased" means ;) but the question is what is the meaning of `if that point happens to be inside the rectangle`. And for me this part of the sentence should be removed from the documentation.

Comment: The meaning is that if origin is in the visible area the lines will intersect on it. So that sentence is exactly what the discussion is about hence shouldn't be removed. Notice that grid path doesn't *start* at the origin since there is not continous path.

Comment: @percusse I see. My understanding was that `if that point happens to be inside the rectangle` is a condition to be `phased`, but now I understand that it is a condition for `it contains the point (0, 0)`. You, and the documentation, win ;) My English loos :(

Comment: @Kpym I don't think it is your English. The very best that can be said is that the documentation is very misleading. It should say `It is important to note that the grid is always “phased” such that, were the point (0,0) to be inside the rectangle, it would lie at an intersection of grid lines.` It has to be a `were it to be the case...` if it affects the way the grid is placed even if that is not the case. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense in English (as you say).